# double qoutes in sql query string

Tags: mysql, string

When trying to create a string to hold the following query for importing a CSV file into MySql the query itself brakes the string i am trying to create.

```
string Query = "load data local infile" + " " + "'" + Filename + "'" + " " + "into table" + " " + Table + "'FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES";
```

Is there anything i do about the `ENCLOSED BY '"'` part?

Thanks

Comment: Escape it with a backslash `'\"'` and don't forget a space before `FIELDS TERMINATED`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by the following method if it helps anyone.

```
 public static void MySqlCSVImport(string Filename, string Table, string Server, string Database, string User, string Password, string Port)
        {
            try
            {
               //enclosed by '"'
                string FixFilePath = Filename.Replace(@":\", ":\\");
                string c = "'" + "\\n" + "'";
                string d = ";";

                string connectionString = "server=" + Server + ";database=" + Database + ";User Id=" + User + ";password=" + Password + "";
                MySqlConnection mySqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
                mySqlConnection.Open();

                string Query = "load data local infile" + " " + "'" + FixFilePath + "'" + " " + "into table" + " " + Table + " FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY" + " " + c + d;

                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(Query, mySqlConnection);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the double quote char using `\` : `"\""`

```
string Query = "load data local infile" + " " + "'" + Filename + "'" + " " + "into table" + " " + Table + "' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES";
```

Comment: Must be missing something, i get {"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES' at line 1"}

Comment: OK, could you provide the final SQL string before executing it?

Answer (score 0):

This is the full method.

```
  public static void MySqlCSVImport(string Filename, string Table, string Server, string Database, string User, string Password)
        {
            try
            {
               //enclosed by '"'
                string connectionString = "server=" + Server + ";database=" + Database + ";User Id=" + User + ";password=" + Password + "";
                MySqlConnection mySqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
                mySqlConnection.Open();

                string Query = "load data local infile" + " " + "'" + Filename + "'" + " " + "into table" + " " + Table + "' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES";

                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(Query, mySqlConnection);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```